# Check if username is available or not with Jquery, Ajax, in Flask and Sqlalchemy database

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Jquery with Ajax to check if username is available or not, I am checking the code twice, loading image is coming but username messages are not displaying and even loading image is not being hidden.

Help me find what went wrong, please

**in Script.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#username").on('input', function(e) {
    $('#msg').hide();
      $('#loading').show();
      if($('#username').val() == null || $('#username').val == ""){
      $('#msg').show();
      $('#msg').html("Username is required field.").css("color", "red");
      $('#loading').hide();
      }
      else{
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/signup",
          data: $('#RegisterForm').serialize(),
          dataType: "html",
          cache: false,
          success: function(msg) {
           $('#msg').show();
           $('#loading').hide();
           $("#msg").html(msg);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#msg').show();
            $('#loading').hide();
            $("#msg").html(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

**python in main.py**

```py
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    --------
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if user:
                resp = jsonify('<span style="\'color:red;\'">Username unavailable</span>')
                resp.status_code = 200
                return resp
            else:
                resp = jsonify('<span style="\'color:green;\'">Username available</span>')
                resp.status_code = 200
                return resp
            hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
            new_user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
            try:
                ---------
    else:
       -------
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

WTForms in html

**HTML code**

```html
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/signup">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2>
    {% for field, errors in form.errors.items() %}
      {{ ', '.join(errors) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <span id="loading" style="display: none;"><img src="{{ url_for('.static', filename='images/loading.gif') }}"></span>
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.cpassword) }}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: did you try to see javascript errors in JavaScript Console in `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome

Comment: did you run server in console/terminal to see all error message?

Comment: did you use `print()` to see what you get on server, what you send to server, and which part of code is executed? It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: I see `try` in your code but .. do you use `print()` in `except` to see errors? If you use `except: pass` then you hide error and you don't know where is the problem.

Comment: You have `if user: ... return resp   else: ... return resp` which means in this place it will always exit this function and it will never execute code after this `if/else` - it will never run `hashed_password = ...`. Do you know how works `return` ?

Comment: yea, I did all that now looking for how to get username form field value without submitting the form in main.py, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

1. Jsonify expects a dictionary.

`jsonify({'message':'ok'})` instead of a string

2. You need on the backend something like that:

```py
# api
@app.route("/check/<username>", methods=["GET"])
def check(username):
    has_username = db.session.query(exists().where(User.username == username)).scalar()
    return jsonify({"exists": has_username})
```

Then in javascript

```js
$('#username-input-id').on('input', function() {
        $.getJSON( "/check/"+$("#username-input-id").val(), function( data ) {
            $("#check").html("<i class='fa fa-list-alt'></i>");
            if (data['exists'] === true){
              $("#check").html("<i style='color:red;' class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i>");
            }
        })
    });
```

where `#check` above is a holder/span to show an icon if username exists. Customise it with your code.

3. Also, flask-wtf allows you to do

`{{ form.email() }}`

instead of

`{{ wtf.form_field(form.email) }}`

if you passed `form=form` as a variable